# Efficient way to calculate cross products, multiply matrix and sum it up

Tags: r, sum, multiple-columns, matrix-multiplication, cross-product

First, let's produce some dummy data for reference:

```r
X <- matrix(runif(27*27, 0, 1), nrow=27, ncol=27)
Y <- matrix(runif(27*27, 0, 1), nrow=27, ncol=27)
```

I have 2 matrices, **X** and **Y**. First, I'm going to calculate the cross product matrix for the first two column vectors of **X** using R's command

```r
cp <- tcrossprod(X[,1], X[,2])
```

The result, `cp`, is now multiplied with the matrix **Y** and all products are summed up:

```r
res <- sum(cp * Y, na.rm=T)
```

Now I'm looking for a fast and thus efficient way to perform this calculation in R for all combinations of column vectors of the matrix **X**. The results should be saved in a third matrix of same dimensions as **X** and **Y**, the matrix **Z**, at **Z[i,j]** for the i-th and j-th columns of **X**.

I already did this job with two stacked for loops:

```r
Z <- matrix(nrow=27, ncol=27)
for (i in 1:ncol(X)) {
 for (j in 1:ncol(X)) {
  cp     <- tcrossprod(X[,i], X[,j])
  Z[i,j] <- sum(cp * Y)
 }
}
```

However, it isn't as fast as I want it to be.

**Thus, I'd be very grateful if you could help me to find a solution which is faster than my stacked for loop solution.**

Many thanks in advance!

PS: I have stored 13 matrices X in a list. The calculations should be performed for all of these matrices. However, I assume that once we find an efficient way for the calculation with 1 matrix, I could use this way together with lapply to do the whole operations on the complete list?!

Comment: IMHO you can algebraic transform the calculation to a form which need less of calculation (use the distributive property). Substitution of for-loops by *apply() is loop-hiding (and has normally no great effect to the run-time).

Comment: Thx for your comment. However, I'm not certain if it is possible in this case. But I'd be happy if you could suggest a solution (maybe I'm just blinded right now). And in regards to apply() - in my personal experience it is much more efficient than the stacked 2 for loop solution ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element `Z[i,j]` can be written as a [bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form#Coordinate_representation). The rest is: puttig together all similar calculations for the matrix `Z`.
You can do:

```
Z <- t(X) %*% Y %*% X  ### or
Z <- crossprod(X, Y) %*% X
```

To compare this calculation with your code:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 27
X <- matrix(runif(n*n, 0, 1), nrow=n, ncol=n)
Y <- matrix(runif(n*n, 0, 1), nrow=n, ncol=n)

Z <- matrix(nrow=n, ncol=n)
for (i in 1:ncol(X)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(X)) {
    cp     <- tcrossprod(X[,i], X[,j])
    Z[i,j] <- sum(cp * Y)
  }
}

Z2 <- t(X) %*% Y %*% X
Z3 <- crossprod(X, Y) %*% X
sum(abs(Z2-Z))
sum(abs(Z3-Z))
```

If `L` is the list of your 13 matrices X. you can do:

```
lapply(L, function(X) crossprod(X, Y) %*% X)
```

Here is the benchmarking:

```
Z1 <- function(X) {
  Z <- matrix(nrow=27, ncol=27)
  for (i in 1:ncol(X)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(X)) {
      cp     <- tcrossprod(X[,i], X[,j])
      Z[i,j] <- sum(cp * Y)
    }
  }
  return(Z)
}

library("microbenchmark")

microbenchmark(Z1=Z1(X), Z2=t(X) %*% Y %*% X, Z3=crossprod(X, Y) %*% X)
#> microbenchmark(Z1=Z1(X), Z2=t(X) %*% Y %*% X, Z3=crossprod(X, Y) %*% X)
#Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq       mean    median       uq      max neval cld
#   Z1 3563.167 3671.6355 4391.00888 3721.3380 3874.617 9423.808   100   b
#   Z2   26.558   27.3420   34.31214   35.5865   39.815   56.426   100  a 
#   Z3   24.779   25.1675   27.43546   26.0965   28.034   47.268   100  a
```

The solutions from Ronak are not faster than the original code, i.e. they are *loop-hiding*:

```
fun <- function(x, y) sum(tcrossprod(X[,x], X[,y]) *Y)

microbenchmark(Z1=Z1(X), 
               R1=outer(seq_len(ncol(X)), seq_len(ncol(X)), Vectorize(fun)), 
               R2=t(sapply(seq_len(ncol(X)), function(x) 
                 sapply(seq_len(ncol(X)), function(y)  sum(tcrossprod(X[,x], X[,y]) *Y)))),
               R3=t(apply(X, 2, function(x) apply(X, 2, function(y) sum(tcrossprod(x, y) *Y)))),
               unit="relative")
# Unit: relative
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#   Z1 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.000000   100  a 
#   R1 1.207583 1.213846 1.195597 1.216147 1.223139  1.060187   100  ab
#   R2 1.225521 1.230332 1.487811 1.230852 1.299253 13.140022   100   b
#   R3 1.156546 1.158774 1.217766 1.160142 2.012623  1.098679   100  ab
```

Comment: Indeed, I first checked quickly how fast the two methods were with Sys.time(). However, my later benchmarking showed that there's no difference between my solution and the solution of Ronak. However, your solution is pretty fast. Thank you so much! (Damn! I can't believe that is so easy and that I couldn't figure it out!)

Comment: BTW - my Y is the list. And X has some NAs rows and columns that cause a list of matrices with NAs only. Any solution around it?

Comment: `as.matrix(Y)` and in X setting all NAs to 0.

Comment: Thanks again. I already tried to set all NAs to 0. But since you recommended it again, I realized that not just X but also Y contains some NAs. Now it works. Mille grazie for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `outer` to apply for every combination of columns

```
fun <- function(x, y) sum(tcrossprod(X[,x], X[,y]) *Y)
outer(seq_len(ncol(X)), seq_len(ncol(X)), Vectorize(fun))
```

Or nested `sapply`

```
t(sapply(seq_len(ncol(X)), function(x) 
         sapply(seq_len(ncol(X)), function(y)  sum(tcrossprod(X[,x], X[,y]) *Y))))
```

Or with `apply`

```
t(apply(X, 2, function(x) apply(X, 2, function(y) sum(tcrossprod(x, y) *Y))))
```

This gives same result as your `Z` with two `for`-loop. I am not sure if there are any performance gains using any of the above approaches since we are not doing anything completely different here.